# Save bitmap to gallery and access it through local notification

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In an app, I am taking a screenshot of the content of a page, and I want to save it in the Gallery, create a local notification with the image in it, and when the user taps on it, it open the image from the Gallery.

As of now, I am able to take the snapshot and save it using this :

```
var path = MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage(context.ContentResolver, bitmap, "TestImage.png", "Snapshot taken");
```

I have a few problems with this approach, I can see the image in the Pictures folders from the Gallery, but the name is not the one I specified in this case "TestImage.png". Also, the path returned from this call has the URI scheme "content://...".

After that, I create the local notification with NotificationCompat.Builder with the embedded image, it works well. But when I try to add the PendingIntent to it to open the image I have an issue with the path returned from InsertImage call. The path returned is : 
content://media/external/images/media/1292

I tried this :

```
var path = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext, "com.myapp.fileprovider", new File(path));
```

but it doesn't work, I get an exception :
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /content:/media/external/images/media/1292

I also tried this :

```
global::Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new File(path)), "image/*")
```

but I receive another exception : 
Android.OS.FileUriExposedException: file:///content%3A/media/external/images/media/1292 exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

This is the code I use to create the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle picStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
                picStyle.BigPicture(bitmap);
                picStyle.SetSummaryText("The snapshot has been saved to your library");

                const int pendingIntentId = 0;
                PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.GetActivity(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, pendingIntentId,
                        new Intent().SetAction(Intent.ActionView)
                            .SetDataAndType(global::Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new File(path)), "image/*"), PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext, "UniqueID")
                    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .SetContentTitle("Security center")
                    .SetContentText("The snapshot has been saved to your library")
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_notification);

                builder.SetStyle(picStyle);

                Notification notification = builder.Build();
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
                const int notificationId = 0;
                notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
```

Do you guys have any idea on how I could save the image with the right name in the Public Gallery folder then access it in the PendingIntent for the local notification ?

Thank you all !

Comment: Are you using forms? Because all i see is native code

Comment: Yes my app is in Xamarin.Forms but the part to save the image and create the local notification, I use services in the native parts for Android and iOS. If you have a solution on the Forms part I'll take it too ! Thanks

Comment: Its better if you do natively as that gives you more control on the matter

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after a few hours of trial and error, I found out the issue, when parsing the path returned from the MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage, I had to use global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse() and not Uri.FromFile(), the latter is only if your path has the URI scheme "file://". By doing that I was able to make the ContentIntent work on the local notification. Only problem now is the name of the file that's not respected.

Comment: Uri.FromFile() is part of the C# System namespace whereas you needed Android.Net.Uri, but i don't think you need the global keyword here, feel free to correct me if i am wrong though